# Client randomly fails to connect to laravel app

Tags: laravel, flutter

I have a laravel app with a frontend website. And two Flutter apps.
The Laravel app is hosted on Hostinger.

Yesterday, I had a surge of users, and I saw that my two apps were not able to connect to the server. Always fot connection timeout for like 5 minutes.
At the same time I tried the website and it was working fine and fast.

5 minutes later both apps started to work like before.

What could that be? I randomly get these issues always on mobile.

I checked Hostinger resource usage and it was at 45%

Comment: 45% means nothing really. Concurrent connections from the other hand...

Comment: have you asked hostinger if you hit any limits? and check whether your flutter hit http 429 (resource exceeded)? as Marcin pointed out, it might be too many active connections and new requests are dropped. shared hosting limits a lot of stuff and will give you http error 429.

Comment: I log all the errors in sentry, I only get the Connection timeout from the Flutter app. It even happened before going to production but not that severe. I am trying to replicate now but it's weirdly working...

Comment: At the time, CPU: 2% - Memory: 500MB out of 1500MB - Throughput (I/O): 0.13KB/s out of 1024KB/s - Entry Processes: 1 out of 30 - Storage performance (IOPS): 3 out of 128 - Processes: 11 out of 60